# Use Explicit Worksheet Names when an SSRS 08 RDL Renders in Excel

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, subreport

My SQL Reporting Service 2008 .rdl file contains a subreport within a rectangle with a forced page-break before it. When it renders in Excel it defines a page break as a worksheet break so it creates the subreport content in a separate worksheet of the Excel Workbook .xls file. How can I name each worksheet? I do not want them to be Sheet1 and Sheet2.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the "PageName" property on an object e.g. a rectangle

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2010/05/16/report-design-naming-excel-worksheets.aspx

Edit: This property is only available for SQL Server 2008 R2 and later versions. If you have SQL Server 2005 or 2008, then it is not possible to name the worksheets.

Comment: Ah no sorry, misread your question tags. This property is only available in SSRS 2008 R2 and later versions. To my knowledge it's not possible to name the worksheets in earlier versions.