# How can I assign sheet names when exporting an SSRS report to Excel?

Tags: excel, reporting-services, spreadsheet, subreport

I am able to have a report with multiple subreports export to Excel with each subreport on a separate tab/sheet using the info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870999/how-to-have-an-ssrs-report-export-to-different-excel-sheets-by-each-subreport) (placing each subreport within a Rectangle control and setting its PageBreak property to "Start").

I hoped that setting the Rectangles' ***PageName*** property would set the sheet names to what I assign there, but no - they are simply "*Sheet 2*", "*Sheet 3*", etc.

So how can I assign a specific value to the sheet names so that those values are used when the SSRS report with its subreports is exported to Excel?

### UPDATE

Trying Hannover Fist's suggestion, I set the Rectangles' PageName property:

[image]

...but the file is still created with generic sheet names:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

On My report, I selected the tablix group on Row Groups window, and I set the Group > PageName property of the group (I could even use a dataset field to name it). I succeeded on that.

In your case, is it possible to create a tablix and do the same, inserting the subreport into this main tablix? It might work.

[image: Group page name thingy]

Answer (score 2):

I usually put the subreport in a **Rectangle** and then give the Rectangle a **Page Name**.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I did that, too, as noted in my question, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you set the "PageName" in the tablix in the sub-reports it should show correctly.

Comment: I created the subreports by dragging an existing .rdl file onto a Subreport control - I see no Tablix...also, the Report (the base report, the only report on the page that isn't a subreport) does have a name for its Tablix ("matrix1"), but what displays on the exported sheet is "Sheet 1" not "matrix1"

Comment: If you set the "PageName" on matrix1 it should flow through. I'm looking at my report that I do this with and that is how I named my tabs.

Comment: I'm using the same .rdl for all of them; they only differ in the value of one of the parameters I provide. They all use the same date range, but are provided a unique value for the third parameter. So, they all use the same .rdl file as a basis.

Comment: I would use matrix1 PageName =" HardCodedString" & Parameters!ThirdParameter.Value

Comment: Makes sense, but it made no difference; with matrix1's PageName set to "=Parameters!Unit.Value" the sheet names on the tabs are still "Sheet1" ... "Sheet6"

Comment: Best of Luck. Not sure what version of SSRS you are using but that could be the issue. [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15484690/use-explicit-worksheet-names-when-an-ssrs-08-rdl-renders-in-excel)

Comment: I don't know either (how to tell?); probably not a very recent one.

Comment: I am still having this problem, and I still don't know what version of SSRS; clicking the "Help" link takes me to a SQL Server 2012 page, but I don't know if it just goes to the most recent version (is it?) or if that really means I'm using SSRS 2012.