# Are there any events I can tap into with VBScript for an SSRS report when it is exported to Excel?

Tags: excel, reporting-services, vbscript, spreadsheet, rdl

I have tried everything I could think of, and other people's suggestions, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928314/how-can-i-assign-sheet-names-when-exporting-an-ssrs-report-to-excel) to specify the sheet names when an SSRS report is exported to Excel by the report runner. So far nothing has worked.

Is there some event that I can tap into and write code (VBScript) for? Data values can be assigned or tweaked using VBScript, but is there a way, in SSRS, to write code for some event such as "OnGenerate" or such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used SSRS, so no idea how it exports.
However, you could attempt to set the application new_Workbook event to trap any new workbook that is opened and check it for some clue/feature that it is a product of the SSRS report tool.

Eg. You could check the workbook name(if there is a clear indication that it's a product of that tool.If you save upon export as something like "mySSRS_Report20160628.xlsx", then you could check for the "mySSRS_" string.

In order to do this you would have to have the 'pagename' appearing consistently in the same cell of the generated sheets, like $A$2 in my example.

You will need an add-in , so open a brand new workbook and make a new class module called cAppEvents and put this in it:

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents app As Application

Private Sub app_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
  Dim i As Long
  If InStr(1, Wb.Name, "mySSRS_", vbTextCompare) Then
        For i = 1 To Wb.Worksheets.Count
              Wb.Worksheets(i).Name = Wb.Worksheets(i).Range("A2").Value
        Next i
        Wb.Save
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
  Set app = Application
End Sub
```

In the ThisWorkbook module of that workbook put this code in:

```
Private newApp As cAppEvents

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Set newApp = New cAppEvents
End Sub
```

Save it off as an Excel add-in. Go to File-->Options-->Addins to manage your add-ins, and check the box with the filename

Test with opening up workbooks with the name having the string "mySSRS_" in them, and with some relevant data in the cell $A$2. 
You get the idea....

Comment: Thanks, but this is not applicable because it would have to be accomplished from SSRS. The Excel file is created via a "Export" option afforded by SSRS. It's probably not possible, I was just grasping at straws.